# Creating object from subset of properties inline in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an object `obj`:

```
let a = b = c = d = 1;
let obj = { a, b, c, d };
```

I would like to create new object inline, with the same properties but one property changed. So far I have this:

```
let other = Object.assign({a: obj.a, b: obj.b, c: obj.c}, {d: 3});
```

and this:

```
let other = Object.assign((({a, b, c}) => ({a, b, c}))(obj), {d: 3});
```

Is there a better way how to do this in ES6? Does functional libraries (like lodash) have any utility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure, `Object.assign` can do it for you. It accepts multiple objects as arguments:

```
 let other = Object.assign({}, obj, {d: 3})
```

Here we created a new "object-receiver" and put it as the first argument. Then goes our source object and, at last, we added new properties. In a case of overlapping keys, the value from latest argument will be used.

Object Spread operator from Henrik's answer does exactly the same thing, but it hasn't standardized yet. `Object.assign` is a part of ES6 and already implemented in [the most recent browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the old object with the [Object Spread operator](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) into a new object and just supply the key you want overwritten with the new value.

```
let obj2 = {
  ...obj,
  d: 4
}

[object Object] {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1,
    d: 4
}
```

As @azium pointed out this is a stage-2 proposal meaning you need to install it into Babel if you have Babel 6.x if 5.x it'll be enabled by default.

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-2
```

Comment: @azium It's a stage-2 ES6 proposal, not ES7.

Comment: Well we're both wrong actually.. now when proposals are committed they become ratified in the year, so I believe this would be an ES2016 proposal

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I am looking for. Meanwhile I found that this will also work `Object.assign(obj, {d: 3});`

Comment: @madox2 - that's just the same as `obj.d = 3`

Comment: `let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj, {d:3});` <- that's how you'd generally do this

Comment: @azium: Only stage 4 proposals will make it into ES2016 / ES7. Spread operator won't make it.

Comment: @adeneo I need to do it inline.

Comment: What do you mean by *"inline"*, do you want to create a new object or not? If you just want to change the value of a property, that should be straight forward without any ES6 stuff ?